# How to remove data from object by date

Tags: javascript, react-native

How do I remove a **property with its value** from **Object** which has added 13 hours ago?

I want to remove data in my object if it has been inside it for more than **12** hours.

**Example:**

```
const myData = {
   user1: {date: '', data: [...]},  // added to myData 1 hour ago
   user2: {date: '', data: [...]},  // added to myData 5 hour ago
   user3: {date: '', data: [...]},  // added to myData 12 hour ago
   user4: {date: '', data: [...]},  // added to myData 13 hour ago
   user5: {date: '', data: [...]},  // added to myData 15 hour ago
}
```

Here I want to remove **user4** and **user5**, as they were added more than 12 hours ago.

Comment: You will have to add a property telling you when you added the object, perhaps a timestamp.

Comment: You can consider it **date property** has a date time value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run an `Object.entries()` iteration every hour and check for old data (Set `maxDate` as desired for each execution):

```js
var obj = {
  user1: {
    date: new Date(2019,6,3,12,0,0)
  },
  user2: {
    date: new Date(2019,6,3,13,0,0)
  }
}

console.log(obj);

var maxDate = new Date(2019,6,3,12,30,0); 
Object.entries(obj).forEach(x => {  
  const date = x[1].date;
  if (date > maxDate) {
    delete obj[x[0]]
  }
})

console.log(obj);
```

---

**EDIT**

Check this example using interval

```
const checkEntries = function() {
    var maxDate = getMaxDate();
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(x => {  
      const date = x[1].date;
      if (date > maxDate) {
        delete obj[x[0]]
      }
    });
}

/*
 * Get the time, 12 hours ago
 */ 
function getMaxDate() {
    const now = new Date();
    const now_tm = now.getTime();
    const maxDate_tm = now_tm - (12*60*60*1000);
    return new Date(maxDate_tm);
}

const timer = setInterval(checkEntries, 3600000);
```

Comment: You can write that as one line: `Object.entries(obj).forEach(x => x[1].date > maxDate && delete obj[x[0]])`

Comment: Could you please tell me, here what is the maxDate.
And I will Calculate **added time** & **current time**.

Comment: Also I am not checking every hours, I will check it some time every minutes or sometimes every seconds, may sometime every day.
Just at every time I check, I should be able to remove properties, exceed 12 hours

Comment: @Muhammad maxdate will be Date.getTime()

Answer (score 2):

You can get the hours between two dates using the following expression:

```js
(addedDate - now) / 3.6e6
```

(where `addedDate` and `now` are `Date` objects). If the result expression is less than or equal to -12, the `addedDate` is older than er exactly 12 hours old.

`addedDate - now` returns the millisecond difference between the two dates. Dividing by 3,600,000 will return that value in hours.

You can use this to periodically filter your entries:

```js
const now = new Date();

const updatedData = Object.entries(myData).reduce((accumulator, [key, value]) => {
    // if time difference is higher than -12, keep the record
    if ((value.addedDate - now) / 3.6e6 > -12) {
        return {...accumulator, [key]: value};
    }
    // otherwise, skip the record, and just return the accumulator
    return accumulator;
}, {});
```

If your date properties are not `Date` objects, convert them to that first.

Comment: Is this fast and performant?
Because May I check at every seconds more than 1000 properties of an object.

Comment: No then my specific snippet is not performant. Object-destructuring more than 1000 properties a second is expensive. You should either go with a more imperative approach, mutating the original object with `delete`, or use another data structure like `Map`. But the general gist is there: Loop over all the properties, check if they are older than 12 hours. If they are, remove them.